# CLLocationManager gets latitude and longitude values at first time when iphone is in Airplane mode.Why?

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager, latitude-longitude

I put my phone in to Airplane mode and tried to get location details.At first time it takes latitude and longitude values,then again I tried to get location,but it fails and throws a kCLErrorLocationUnknown error.But according to Apple when Airplane mode, it should not take any signals.but at first time it takes.why ?
Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Always check the time of the CLLocations you get in the callbacks, and discard ones that came from a time well before before your application was launched...

Comment: Probably an Apple bug, but you should always check to see if the long/lat is out of bounds when you get a didUpdateLocation callback.

Answer (score 3):

Locations can be cached from last use of location service. To check how recent is the location, check the `timestamp` property of the location.

Answer (score 1):

When you start the `CLLocationManager` it will return the last known location, this is to speed things up a bit.

Since it can takes some time to get the location from GPS, iOS will first try and get a location by triangulation. based on cell tower information or WiFi.

The [`CLLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLLocation) class has a `timestamp` property that allows you to check if the location is up to date.